# How to show a "cover page" for a Servicestack api site / Redirect to another website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

We have a "webapi" site built using servicestack and everything works great

Now browsing to the site brings up the ~/metadata page

Is there an option to show a custom stub page as in - pls visit the main site at www.abc.com

or better yet, redirect the browser to www.abc.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **EndpointHostConfig**, you can set MetadataRedirectPath and DefaultRedirectPath. However, looking at the source code MetadataRedirectPath and DefaultRedirectPath both **expect a relative url**.

If you need more control or want to redirect to an outside site then you **can intercept the entire request**. So in your specific case you can do the following:

In AppHost configuration

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{
    RawHttpHandlers =
    {
         httpReq => httpReq.PathInfo == "/metadata" ? 
            new RedirectHttpHandler { AbsoluteUrl = "http://www.abc.com" } 
            : null
     },
});
```

**Edit: Changed code to reflect mythz suggestion.**

Comment: Using the built in `new RedirectHttpHandler { AbsoluteUrl = "http://www.abc.com" }` should work as well, and also supports both ASP.NET or HttpListener hosts.

Comment: @mythz thank you and thank you for the great work on ServiceStack, i have another question on encrypting the messages and later found some reference to a post from you from last year where it was in the works but haven't found anything else, any pointers on if/when/how etc. ? my question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098839/encrypting-messages-over-servicestack