# Encrypting messages over ServiceStack

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

Given an app that needs to exchange info such as ConsumerKey/ConsumerSecret for oAuth from

```
- server running "WebApi" over ServiceStack
- consumer is a desktop app
```

Looking to encrypt the messages using Public/Private keys which are already in place

Is there any support for encrypting/decrypting messages, hopefully transparently ? i.e. the encrypting/decryption is handled via say Filters on the server ?

OR

any workaround on how to do this ?

FYI - the server already requires SSL and requests are authenticated, however the registration is free/automated, hence the need for encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

The [Encrypted Messaging Feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Encrypted-Messaging) released in [v4.0.42](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2015/release-notes.md#v4042-release-notes) now enables a secure channel for all Services offering protection to clients who can now easily send and receive encrypted messages over unsecured HTTP.

---

There's no published support for Message Level encryption built into the [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) at the moment, although this is something we're thinking of adding in the future. Below is an example of an approach you could try with ServiceStack today for exploratory purposes (it will require more R&D on your part to come up with a good solid design), and as this is an area that may change in future, it's not a use-case we're supporting right now, but here's something that could work with ServiceStack as it is now:

```
class EncryptedRequest 
{ 
    //Name of the request type 
    public string Type { get; set; }

    //Serialized Request DTO using something like JSON 
    public string EncryptedBody { get; set; }

    //optional: let server the private key that was used (if multiple) 
    public string PrivateKeyMd5Hash { get; set; }
} 

class EncryptedResponse 
{ 
    //Name of the response type 
    public string Type { get; set; } 

    //Serialized Response DTO 
    public string EncryptedBody { get; set; } 

    //optional 
    public string PublicKeyMd5Hash { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is a convenient [CryptUtils wrapper](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/CryptUtils.cs) that makes it easy to create Public/Private keys as well as being able to Encrypt/Decrypt text using them.

Then you can have a single service, and do something like:

```
class EncryptedService : Service 
{ 
    const string PublicKey = ...; 
    const string PrivateKey = ...; 

    EncryptedResponse Any(EncryptedRequest request) 
    { 
        var requestType = Type.GetType("{0}.{1}" 
            .Fmt(typeof(EncryptedRequest).Namespace, request.Type)); 

        var json = CryptUtils.Decrypt(PrivateKey, request.EncryptedBody); 
        var requestDto = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString(json,requestType); 
        var responseDto = GetAppHost().Config.ServiceController
            .Execute(requestDto, base.RequestContext); 

        return new EncryptedResponse { 
           Type = responseDto.GetType().Name, 
           EncryptedBody = CryptUtils.Encrypt(PublicKey, responseDto.ToJson()), 
        }; 
    } 
}
```

The client would also need a copy of the Public/Private key pair which you would exchange out-of-band.

Comment: GetAppHost() in GetAppHost().Config.ServiceController does not resolve, looks like it's changed to GetResolver() but unable to get it to work ! any pointers ? thanks

Comment: Just [added GetAppHost() back](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/383cc4722aa27312dd748175839a4624d454bc57) you just need to cast it. This is for exploratory purposes only which I'll leave the rest up to you to research, as I don't have any more time to spend on this.

Comment: @mythz is there anything more recent on decrypting requests in the framework since you wrote this?